# как делается вывод в javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Я хочу вывести время в данный момент, но не знаю как. Я только начал изучать Javascript, но не могу найти нормальный сайт с хорошим объяснением. Поэтому прошу помочь мне с выводом времени в настоящий момент на Javascript.

Comment: Один из способов, уточните вопрос.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418405/making-a-live-clock-in-javascript

Comment: Один из сайтов с хорошим объяснением JavaScript — https://learn.javascript.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const date = new Date(); // получаем дату

const h = date.getHours(); // получаем часы из даты
const m = date.getMinutes(); // минуты
const s = date.getSeconds(); // секунды
const ms = date.getMilliseconds(); // миллисекунды

console.log(`${h}:${m}:${s}:${ms}`); // выводим
```

Вот так из этого можно сделать часы:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const date = new Date(); // получаем дату

  const h = date.getHours(); // получаем часы из даты
  const m = date.getMinutes(); // минуты
  const s = date.getSeconds(); // секунды
  const ms = date.getMilliseconds(); // миллисекунды

  console.clear();
  console.log(`${h}:${m}:${s}:${ms}`); // выводим

}, 0001);
```